# Displaying Kendo UI line chart on Kendo UI tooltip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

I want to show a line chart on tooltip like below - 
[Line Chart on tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBUjA.jpg)
For this I created chart and embedding it in tooltip using *content* property

```
content: function (e) {
          return $("#" + $(e.target).attr("id") + "_tooltip").html();
       }
```

The issue is I want to display tooltip on a series, which is not happening right now. But if I plot same chart on body instead of embedding it on tooltip its working fine.

Is there anything extra I need to configure to handle such scenario?

[dojo link](http://dojo.telerik.com/EJoco/8)

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far? Maybe create a DOJO or CodePen?

Comment: @ezanker [Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EJoco/8) I created a dojo. Please take a look.

Comment: What exactly in the dojo is not working? when i hover over the show tooltip text, I see a chart in the tooltip.

Comment: @ezanker When you hover on series connector (the dots on series line), it should display the value as tooltip on chart. But in this case if I plot a graph on tooltip and when I hover on connector dots the value is not being visible. Thanks for following this up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your chart tooltip a content template and then create the chart when the tooltip is shown.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/MpzwvE)**

Code:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div id="myTooltip">
    <span>Some Text here</span>
    <div id="myChart"></div>
    <span>hover the connectors, not showing tootip</span>
  </div>
</script>

   function CreateTooltipChart(){
    // Satter line chart embedded in tooltip
      $("#myChart").kendoChart({
        chartArea: {
          height: 200,
          width: 310
        },
        title: {
          text: "Charge current vs. charge time"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
          type: "scatterLine"
        },
        series: [{
          data: [[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40]]
        }],
        xAxis: {
          max: 35,
          labels: {
            format: "{0}m"
          },
        },
        yAxis: {
          max: 50,
          labels: false
        },
        //tooltip for chart is set here
        tooltip: {
          visible: true,
          format: "{1}% in {0} minutes"
        }
      });     
    }

    // Tooltip on span element
    var tooltip = $('.show-tooltip').kendoTooltip({
      autoHide: false,
      position: "right",
      width: 312,
      //height: 300,
      show: function(e){
        CreateTooltipChart();
      },
      content: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ezanker